# Attempting to move modally programatically through a UIAlert

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am currently trying to go from one view to another modally via an alert pop-up when you press ok.

The problem is the code I'm trying to use isn't moving from one screen to the other. I'm not sure why.

The Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func helpButtonPushed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Help has been sent", message: "Please move towards the Student Services Area. ", preferredStyle: .alert)

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            //Show the quiz. 
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "QuizViewcontroller", bundle:nil)

            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Quiz") as! QuizViewController
            self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

        })

        alertController.addAction(okAction)
    }
}
```

The two viewControllers I'm trying to use: ViewController and QuizViewController.

[image: View Contollers]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "isn't working". Never use those words without clearly specifying what is actually happening and what should be happening. Do you get any error messages? [Edit] your question to include all relevant details about your issue.

Comment: QuizViewController not QuizViewcontroller maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your view controller gets presented without using the alert. If works fine: present your alert first. I do not see the code which presents your alert first.
Below code works fine:

@IBAction func helpButtonPushed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Hello", message: "Hi How are you", preferredStyle: .alert)

```
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2")
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)

    })

    alert.addAction(okAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `UIStoryBoard` Put  `QuizViewcontroller` is not good naming convention Use `Main` instead which is by default or you can check it with your project's deployment info -
[image]

```
  let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
```